# How to Create Laravel Role and permission model based

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

hello everyone ,
I hope all are you fine. I am using laravel 8. i want add role and permission on model based. frontend use on react 17. i am trying to role and permission spatie. but i am not sure spatie model based role and permission module given. so please give me suggestion regarding this
Regards
Bilal

Comment: I found it very easy to make it from scratch, just create Role and Permission models with their db tables and the pivot table, create some helper functions like hasRole or hasPermission and you are good to go.

Comment: Why are you not sure about using spatie's package?

Comment: because i don't want to changing on controller.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Laratrust](https://laratrust.santigarcor.me/) works really fine for me